# speed of rotation in rads/sec

Tags: dc-motor

Can anyone help me with the speed of rotation in rads/sec.

I am trying to find the equation for it.

I have 730 rpm as my motor speed. It is a DC motor.

So far the equation i have is:  2pi x 730/60

And the answer is 76.445.

Is this the correct equation to use tho find speed of rotation in rads/sec?

Thanks.

Comment: looks good to me. It's roughly rpm/10.

Comment: check the definition of a radian then : https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/radians.html

Comment: This is *really basic*.  There are 2 pi radians in a circle, and there are 60 seconds in a minute.  The rest is simple grade-school arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Omega=2\pi f= \dfrac{2\pi N}{60} = \dfrac{\pi N}{30} $$
$$\Omega=\dfrac{3.14\cdot 730}{30}= 76.4 [rad/s]$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if a motor turns with N rpm, it's (angular) speed becomes

$$ \omega \ [\frac{rad}{s}]=\frac{N \ rev}{1\ min}.\frac{1\ min}{60\ s}.\frac{2\pi  \ rad}{1\ rev}\approx \frac{N}{10}[\frac{rad}{s}]$$